# Form com múltiplas janelas

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress

Estou tentando fazer um formulário com múltiplas janelas, mas não entendo o que está dando de errado.

[Codigo para teste](http://codepen.io/MarciusMcflay/pen/xVbZwo)

O que quero fazer é que ao clicar nos botões ele esconda e mostra o próximo formulário.

**UPDATE**

Segui a sugestão do @afonso, mas ainda não está funcionando, inclusive atualizei meu codepen, lá também não funciona.

```
$( window ).load(function() {
    $('form button').on('click', trataForm);

    function trataForm(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var $bloco = $(event.currentTarget).parents('div');

        $bloco.removeClass('active');

        if($(this).hasClass('next')){
            if ($bloco.is(':last-child'))
                $(event.currentTarget).parents('form').submit(); //<-aqui
            else
                $bloco.next().addClass('active');
        }else{
            if (!$bloco.is(':first-child'))
                $bloco.prev().addClass('active');
        }
    }
});
```

Eu estou no WordPress. Fiz um plugin que adiciona o `css` e `js`. Ele obriga você a fazer as chamadas dentro de uma function, ou `$( window ).load`, e por algum motivo ele sempre cai na primeira condição (onde coloquei o comentário '<-aqui'). Alguém que sabe como resolver isso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sugiro uma abordagem mais simples (claro, você pode completar e incrementar  o código):

```js
$('form button').on('click', trataForm);

function trataForm(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var $bloco = $(event.currentTarget).parents('div');

  $bloco.removeClass('active');

  if ($bloco.is(':last-child'))
    $(event.currentTarget).parents('form').submit();
  else
    $bloco.next().addClass('active');
}
```

```css
form > div {
  display: none;
}
form > div.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <div class="bloco1 active">
    <p>Conteúdo do bloco 1</p>
    <button>Next</button>
  </div>
  <div class="bloco2">
    <p>Conteúdo do bloco 2</p>
    <button>Next</button>
  </div>
  <div class="bloco3">
    <p>Conteúdo do bloco 3</p>
    <button type="submit">Next</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Em resumo, o que acontece: todas as `div` filhas do `form` estão ocultas, exceto aquela que está ativa no momento (marcada com a classe `active`). Ao clicar no botão "Next", o script procura a `div` "pai" do botão que disparou o clique, remove a classe e seta `active` para a próxima `div` da lista - se for a última, explicitamente aplica a classe na primeira (`bloco1`).

Comment: Cara muito mais simples. E se na último div eu quiser que ele de um submit com todas as informações?

Comment: @MarciusLeandro alterei a lógica para, ao invés de mandar de volta ao primeiro bloco, o último botão submeter o formulário.

Comment: @afonoso foi mal suas resposta é muito boa, mas ainda assim não resolveu meu problema, apesar de funcionar aqui no stack, não funciona nem no code open, nem na minha pagina.

Answer (score 0):

Tive que alterar levemente o seu `HTML` mas, basicamente, o que estava faltando para o seu código funcionar era a inclusão do `jQuery`. Sem ele, `$(window).load()` e mais outros métodos não existem. Incluí um `snippet` aqui na resposta, e também fiz uma nova [pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NNPrGG), usando o código da sua *pen* antiga.

Atente para alguns erros conceituais no `HTML`. O fato de você estar no WordPress ou não não deve interferir com o funcionamento de código `front end`. Garanta também que a sua versão do `jQuery` será chamada e carregada antes de você rodar esta sua rotina.

```js
$(window).load(function() {
    $('form button').on('click', trataForm);

    function trataForm(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var $bloco = $(event.currentTarget).parents('div');

        $bloco.removeClass('active');

        if ($(this).hasClass('next')) {
            if ($bloco.is(':last-child'))
                $(event.currentTarget).parents('form').submit();
            else
                $bloco.next().addClass('active');
        } else {
            if (!$bloco.is(':first-child'))
                $bloco.prev().addClass('active');
        }
    }
});
```

```css
div.mult_form {
    border: 1px dotted black;
    padding: 20px;
}

form > div.mult_form {
    display: none;
}

form > div.mult_form.active {
    display: block; 
}

.mf_button {
    display: inline;
    margin-top: 10px !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
    <h2> Meu Formulario </h2>
    <div id="0" class="mult_form active">
        Valor 1: <input type="text" id="idvalor1" name="valor1">
        <button class="mf_button next">next</button>
    </div>
        
    <div id="1" class="mult_form">
        Data de Aniversario: 
        <input type="date" id="idbirthdate" name="birthdate">
        <button class="mf_button preview">voltar</button> 
        <button class="mf_button next">next</button>
    </div>
        
    <div id="2" class="mult_form">
        Produto Usado: 
        <select id="idproduct" name="product">
            <option value="katlei">Katléia</option>
            <option value="kairo">Kairo</option>
        </select>
        <button class="mf_button preview">voltar</button> 
        <button class="mf_button next">submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: O que voce alterou no html, fora tirar os <br>? Porque eu mantive meu html só adicionei acima do form scrip do ajax, mas mesmo assim não funcionou. E também não entendi porque o meu codepen não funciona e o seu sim.

Comment: Minha pen e meu snippet funcionam por conta da inclusão do `jQuery`, conforme mencionei na resposta. As alterações do `HTML` foram sim a retirada dos `<br>` e, se não me engano, o fechamento de algumas `<div>` nos locais corretos

Comment: No pen tem que adicionar o JQuery? Ele já não tem por padrão? Você pode me dizer onde tinha div fechada errada? Porque pode ser isso, o wordpress que gera esse html e ele gera chei de <p> que não ficha e </br>

Comment: Achei no codeopen onde que tem de add o jQuery ai o codeopen passou a funcionar. Bom tenho que ver como o meu plugin add wordpress o Jquery talvez seja isso.

Comment: Descobri qual o erro é exatamente ter os <br>, Porque ele pega o next errado.

Comment: @MarciusLeandro que bom que deu certo. No `pen`, você tem que adicionar qualquer biblioteca que for usar. Se a resposta lhe ajudou, marque-a como correta